# doing join between two tables based on item,loc combinations

Tags: sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

item table:

```
item   loc    month    year
watch  delhi   1       2020
watch  delhi   2       2020
watch  delhi   4       2020
watch  delhi   5       2020
tv     mumbai  1       2020
tv     mumbai  2       2020
tv     mumbai  5       2020
```

month table:

```
month    year
  1      2020
  2      2020
  3      2020
  4      2020
  5      2020
```

i want to join the item and month tables using right join...but here is some complexity....what i want is i want the join for each item,loc combination...i.e. for watch item it will be different join and for tv item it will be different join with month table.

Output:

```
item   loc    month    year
watch  delhi   1       2020
watch  delhi   2       2020
null   null    3       2020
watch  delhi   4       2020
watch  delhi   5       2020
tv     mumbai  1       2020
tv     mumbai  2       2020
null   null    3       2020
null   null    4       2020
tv     mumbai  5       2020
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would prefer a result set without the `NULL` values.  That would be:

```
select il.item, il.loc, m.month, m.year
from (select distinct item, loc from items) il cross join
     months m;
```

If you really want `NULL` values, you can use an additional `left join`:

```
select i.item, i.loc, m.month, m.year
from (select distinct item, loc from items) il cross join
     months m left join
     items i
     on i.item = il.item and i.loc = il.loc
order by il.item, il.loc, m.year, m.month;
```

The `order by` is important so the rows will correspond correctly.